# How to make a Rectangle() and a DatePicker overlap?

Tags: swift, swiftui, positioning, overlap

So I'm trying to move the rectangle so that it looks like there's a little point at the bottom of the DatePicker() UI element:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimeSelectorView: View {
    @State private var selectedDay: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDay, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("")
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
             .clipped()
             .background(Color.white)
             .cornerRadius(15)
            Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 45))
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear. Would you demo somehow what you try to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you need a `ZStack`?

Comment: Yeah, using the Stack worked well...I was messing around with them earlier and couldn't get it to work but I did, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create overlapping Views you can use a `ZStack`.

> SwiftUI has a dedicated stack type for creating overlapping content,
>   which is useful if you want to place some text over a picture for
>   example. It’s called ZStack, and it works identically to the other two
>   stack types [HStack, VStack].

In the below example, the `DatePicker` will be placed behind the `Rectangle`:

```
ZStack {
    DatePicker(...)
    Rectangle()
}
```

You can find more information in this tutorial: [How to layer views on top of each other using ZStack?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-layer-views-on-top-of-each-other-using-zstack)